# Surface Pro 2 DisplayPort 1.2 since recent update

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, displayport, microsoft-surface

I'm using the Surface Pro 2 and two Dell U2414H Displays connected via DaisyChain (Displayport to first monitor and then from the first monitor to the second monitor).

This worked a long time, but I recently did a [Windows/Firmware Update and it doesn't work anymore](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/install-update-activate/2-update-history). Not even one Display having the Displaypoirt 1.2 enabled. My Intel Graphics Driver is now 10.18.10.3496 (07.03.2014). But I'm not sure if this is the reason of the problem.

When setting the Dell U2414H back to Displayport 1.1 configuration, windows does find the monitor again.

When choosing Displayport 1.2 on the monitor, Windows does not recognize the display anymore. **Strange but it seems like the Displayport 1.2 compatibility has gone**

(Example of the Dell Menu to enable Displayport 1.2):
[image]

So my question is - **how can I make the Surface compatible with Displyport 1.2 again?** (and then in a second term trying to enable the daisychain configuration again)

Comment: There seem to be some more people facing the same issue: http://www.surfaceforums.net/threads/finally-daisy-chaining-monitors-with-displayport-1-2.6500/page-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the exact same setup, Surface Pro 2 and two Dell 2414H monitors. I also had the exact same problem this morning. Thankfully I have it all working again. Unfortunately I can't explain what may have eventually did it, but here is everything I did. Hopefully this will help you.

First, I have had this problem before when my Surface Pro 2 goes to sleep. Sometimes when it comes back I'll be down one monitor. My solution before was always to unplug all Display Port cables on both monitors, then unplug power to both monitors, then shut down Surface Pro 2, then plug everything back in, then start back up. This did not fix my problem this morning.

So I next hit up Google and found your question here and had a moment of despair... same question, no answers! Noooooo.....

Next, I went and downloaded the [July 2014 Surface Pro 2 drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38826). I used the graphics driver installer there. I don't remember what the driver version/date was before, but after this install it matches yours, 10.18.10.3496 (07.03.2014). This still did not work, so I went back to step 1 of unplugging and replugging cables.

Success! I finally got both monitors back. However, one monitor was now flickering on and off. I checked the refresh rate and it was set to 59hz for some reason. I changed this to 60hz and it has since stopped flickering.

Finally I noticed on the same monitor properties page that the driver was reporting as a generic monitor. So I headed over to the [Dell U2414H drivers](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/dell-u2414h/drivers) page and installed those drivers.

As of right now things are still working. However these monitors are very frustrating and I would not be surprised if they stopped working again at any moment.